# Pages in Printing

Tags: printing, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

Is it possible to know which page I am printing in MS Word? Or which page has been printed recently? I am trying to find out using vsto. There are methods like `Application.PrintOut()` 
and property like `Application.PrintPreview` but nothing to find which page I am printing.